# How to get second max value of each row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

This gets the maximum value for each row in a pandas dataframe in a new column named 'max' and then
creates a new list named maxV from that column.

```
df["max"] = df1.max(axis=1)
maxV = df['max'].tolist()
```

How can i get the second max value of each row in a new column named 'sec_max'?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Function to get the second maximum value in each row
def get_second_max(row):
    # Use np.partition to efficiently find the second largest value
    second_largest = np.partition(row, -2)[-2]
    return second_largest

# Apply the function to each row and store the result in 'sec_max' column
df['sec_max'] = df.apply(get_second_max, axis=1)

# Convert the 'sec_max' column to a new list named maxV
sec_maxV = df['sec_max'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `np.sort`:

```py
df[['sec_max', 'maxV']] = np.sort(df, axis=1)[:, -2:]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  sec_max  maxV
0     1     3     2        2     3
1     6     4     5        5     6
2     7     8     8        8     8
```

---

`df` used:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     1     3     2
1     6     4     5
2     7     8     8
```

Answer (score 0):

here you are:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"col1": [420, 380, 390], 
        "col2": [50, 40, 45], 
        "col3": [102, 60, 700]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
    currentRow=df.iloc[i].values
    max1=currentRow.max()
    max2=currentRow.min()
    for j in range(0,len(currentRow)):
        if(currentRow[j]>max2 and currentRow[j]<max1):
            max2=currentRow[j]
    print(max1,max2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

`df['2nd largest'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.nlargest(2).values[-1],axis=1)`

Example Input:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[3,4,5], 'c':[2,1,10]})
print (df)
```

df:

```
   a  b   c
0  1  3   2
1  2  4   1
2  3  5  10
```

code:

```
df['2nd largest'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.nlargest(2).values[-1],axis=1)
print (df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b   c  2nd largest
0  1  3   2            2
1  2  4   1            2
2  3  5  10            5
```

Comment: Great and very simple!